# RabbitMQ MQTT wildcard routing failed to deliver messages

Tags: push-notification, routes, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I've recently installed the rabbitmq mqtt websocket plugin. but I'm facing a problem when I use wildcard routing. The published messages to a wildcard topic are not delivered to the subscribers who are offline.

for an example
a subscriber is subscribed to a topic like `/city/area/lane/house/user`
a publisher is publishing to a topic like `/city/+/+/+/user`

The messages are delivered without any hustle when the subscribers are online. but when subscribers are offline the messages fail to deliver. 
the QOS level I've used is 1.

can anyone help me please.

Comment: You can't publish to a wildcard topic, I assume you have your example the wrong way round. Also you have made no mention of what QOS you are subscribing at

Comment: Thank you for the reply.The QOS level I've used is 1. because by default RabbitMQ server downgrades the QOS level to 1 if we use 2.